# R: How to cut a numeric variable in grouped tbl_df using dynamic variable length breaks

Tags: r, dplyr, categorization

I wonder how to create categorical variable using dynamic breaks for grouped numeric variables using dplyr.

Here is the toy example, say, using `mtcars` data and I want to categorize cars into low and high `mpg` classes when grouped by `vs` and `am`. A car will be classified as low mpg car if its `mpg` is below the mean `mpg` of its group. Here is my way of doing this

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  tbl_df() %>% 
  group_by(vs, am) %>% 
  mutate(lowMPG = ifelse(mpg < mean(mpg), "Yes", "No"))
```

However my actual problem is more general where the breaks can be a vector instead of a scalar for each group. Also the function used to compute the breaks might come from external source. So you might have the following object stored in `brk` in R to cut the `mpg` variable.

```
vs    am  breakPoint_1  breakPoint_2   breakPoint_3
0     0   14.0          15.0           17.0
0     1   17.0          19.0
1     0   19.0          21.0
1     1   28.4
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr`, and `pmap` from `purrr`. The main thing is to create the break point for all unique combination of `am` and `vs` first.

```
brk_point <- tibble(am = c(0,0,1,1),
                vs = c(0,1,0,1),
                brk = list(c(-Inf, 14,15,17, Inf),
                           c(-Inf, 17,19, Inf),
                           c(-Inf, 19,21, Inf),
                           c(-Inf, 27.4, Inf)))

foo <- mtcars %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  left_join(., brk_point) 

foo_cut <- foo %>%
  dplyr::mutate(cut_mpg = purrr::pmap(list(.$mpg,.$brk),
                                      cut, 
                                      include.lowest = TRUE))
```

You can also use `unnest` to organise it.